# find text between > < for a given variable and change text to something else

Tags: xml

If I search file eg. file.xml for s_webdomain I will get:

```
        <hostname oa_var="s_webhost">hostname</hostname>
     <externURL oa_var="s_external_url">https://hostname:4450</externURL>
     <directory_index oa_var="s_directory_index">index.html</directory_index>
     <webentryhost oa_var="s_webentryhost">hostname.host</webentryhost>
     <webentrydomain oa_var="s_webentrydomain">services.uk</webentrydomain>
     <domain oa_var="s_webdomain">services.uk</domain>
     <server_ip_address oa_var="s_server_ip_address"/>
     <!-- Configuration files -->
     <!-- SSL Variables -->
     <url_protocol oa_var="s_url_protocol">http</url_protocol>
     <web_ssl_directory oa_var="s_web_ssl_directory">/u03/app/ENV/gs/inst/ENV_01-bsapp01/certs</web_ssl_directory>
     <local_url_protocol oa_var="s_local_url_protocol">http</local_url_protocol>
```

I want to replace services.uk no matter what it says to :

`<domain oa_var="s_webdomain">SOME_DIFFERENT_TEXT</domain>`

`$ grep s_webdomain file.xml | awk -F '>' '{print $2}' | awk -F '<' '{print $1}'`

services.uk

Any ideas about how to change services.uk to SOME_DIFFERENT_TEXT ? probably needs a sed command, but I'm not sure .

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give us a more complete example of your file? Attempting to parse structured languages like XML or HTML with basic text parsing tools and regular expressions _can_ work, but it is very fragile and bad practice. If you give us a fuller example of the file, we can help you do this using dedicated XML parsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your Example Document having all the tags (& all the matching lines you want) on single lines , I would make this Simple Perl Command to change that text :

```
#
# perl -i.bak -p -e "s/(<.*>)(.*)(<.*>)/\${1}SOME_DIFFERENT_TEXT\${3}/ if /s_webdomain/" file.xml 
#
# diff file.xml file.xml.bak 
10c10
<      <domain oa_var="s_webdomain">SOME_DIFFERENT_TEXT</domain>
---
>      <domain oa_var="s_webdomain">services.uk</domain>
#
```

Simple Perl Command is making backup file with `*.bak` extention , & printing every line in the given text file , & using a regex to match the lines with `s_webdomain` , then substituting the central text with `SOME_DIFFERENT_TEXT` , to generate the output file.

Diff Command shows what has changed , by comparing updated contents in the text file with the original contents in the backup file.

Perl may already be installed & available. This Solution is very quick & It can be extended with tweaking.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is perfect.

Comment: perl -i.bak -p -e "s/(<.*>)(.*)(<.*>)/\${1}/u03/app/jdk32/jre/lib/security/cacerts\${3}/ if /s_ssl_truststore/" $THE_FILE                  - it doesn't like / it seems. I get Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "s/(<.*>)(.*)(<.*>)/${1}/u03"
syntax error at -e line 1, near "s/(<.*>)(.*)(<.*>)/${1}/u03"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
Is there a way to avoid the / problem in perl ? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @user2346372 and that's why using an [XML-aware tool](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/720578/100397) is more reliable

Comment: I think you did not read that comment , OP is asking a **new** question , @roaima

Comment: What you have given may have a Simple Solution , but it is not good to ask new questions in comments & answer them via comments. I suggest you Post a new Question with what you want & what you are trying & what the Issue is. I think , we can give a Simple Solution to that Question. @user2346372

Comment: In other words : OP has a new Problem , in a new Case , which is not because of xml-awareness , but because of wrong syntax. In xmlstarlet too , if we give "-- update" or "----value" or use "////" or "====" , we will get syntax issues. @roaima

Comment: not to worry, all sorted. Just needed to add \ before every /. Thanks all.

Comment: Oh , great to know that ! That was the Simple Solution which I had , but I could not put in the comments because (1) StackExchange "Policy" is like that , not to answer new questions in the comments (2) In the "Small Comment Area" , I can not easily explain which "/" to escape , & which "/" not to escape ! [[ You may want to know that putting "\" in front of "/" has the terminology "ESCAPING" , in general ! ]] ++ [[ In the Answer , I mention "It can be extended with tweaking" & I was happy to know that you have already used this Answer to extend to your new Case ! ]] @user2346372

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with a document in a structured document format, the best processing tool are the ones that are aware of that format.

The following uses the XML processing tool `xmlstarlet` to replace the value of all `domain` nodes that have an `ou_var` attribute with the value `s_webdomain`:

```bash
xmlstarlet edit \
    --update '//domain[@oa_var = "s_webdomain"]' \
    --value "SOME_DIFFERENT_TEXT" file
```

or, using short options,

```bash
xmlstarlet ed \
    -u '//domain[@oa_var = "s_webdomain"]' \
    -v "SOME_DIFFERENT_TEXT" file
```

The command uses an XPath query, `//domain[@oa_var = "s_webdomain"]`, to address all the possible places in the input document that will be updated.  Each matching entity will have its value updated to, in this case, the string `SOME_DIFFERENT_TEXT`.

The initial `//` in the Xpath pattern means that the `domain` node may be found *anywhere*.  Usually, one knows the document's structure and would instead specify a more exact path to the node(s) that one intends to process.

You may add `--inplace` (`-L`) after `edit` to make the changes in the document "in-place".

To affect multiple nodes, for example, the `webentrynode` with an `oa_var` value of `s_webentrydomain`:

```bash
xmlstarlet edit \
    --update '//domain[@oa_var = "s_webdomain"]' \
    --value "SOME_DIFFERENT_TEXT" \
    --update '//webentrydomain[@oa_var = "s_webentrydomain"]' \
    --value "SOME_DIFFERENT_TEXT" file
```

---

To *extract* the value(s), you would use `xmlstarlet select`, like so:

```bash
xmlstarlet select \
    --template \
    --value-of '//domain[@oa_var = "s_webdomain"]' \
    -nl file
```

or, using short options,

```bash
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//domain[@oa_var = "s_webdomain"]' -n file
```

Comment: that looks interesting, thanks. I'll see if we can load xmlstarlet

Answer (score 1):

You can just use awk by itself:

To test it:
`awk '{sub(/s_webdomain\">services.uk/,"s_webdomain\">some_new_text"); print}' file.xml`

and to write it inplace:
`awk -i inplace '{sub(/s_webdomain\">services.uk/,"s_webdomain\">some_new_text"); print}' file.xml`

Comment: I think this will change all occurrences of services.uk to SOME_NEW_TEXT. I only want to change it for a specific line in the code. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: The original command would have, so I updated it to address the one particular occurrence